# Prove $f(x^p)=g(x)^p$ in finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Suppose $q=p^n$ , $p $ is prime. $F=F_q$ is a finite field . For $f(x)\in F[x]$,  prove there exists $g(x)\in F[x]$ such that $$f(x^p)=(g(x))^p $$

I think the point is to use the fact that $char(F)=p$. But I'm confused in the process to find an exact $g(x)$ to make its power equal $f(x^p)$. So I'm reconsidering just proof it without find $g(x)$. How can I achieve this.

Comment: What are $f(x)$ and $g(x)$?  What do you mean by the polynomial on $F$?  Are $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ specific polynomials?  Arbitrary polynomials?

Comment: Since $F$ has characteristic $p$, you can pull a power of $p$ out of every monomial in $f(x^p)$, and whatever polynomial you get after is the desired $g(x)$, e.g. $a_0^p+a_1^px^p+a_2^px^{2p}=(a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2)^p$. You can assume every coefficient in $F$ is a $p$-power since the Frobenius is an automorphism of $F$.

Comment: I want to express that $f(x)$ is polynomial which its coefficients in $F$ and they are arbitrary.

Comment: @ Ben West I still don't fully understand your explanation for every coefficient in $F$ is a p-power. I have an attempt like this. For each $\alpha \in F^*$,$|F|=p^n-1$,hence $order(\alpha)|p^n-1$, thus there exists $d$ such that $order(\alpha)=p^d-1$. Then $\alpha^{p^d}=\alpha\Rightarrow((\alpha)^{p^{d-1}})^p=\alpha $. Therefor we can conclude that every coefficient in $F$ is a p-power. Am I right?

Comment: @LOIS Not quite, since $p^n-1$ might have divisors not of form $p^d-1$. Instead, look at the Frobenius map $\varphi\colon F\to F:a\mapsto a^p$. It's a field homomorphism since $(a+b)^p=a^p+b^p$ in char $p$, etc., and it's injective, for if $a^p=0$, then necessarily $a=0$. So $\varphi$ is surjective as an injective map on a finite set. So every element of $F$ has form $a^p$ for some $a\in F$.

Comment: @ Ben West  That's explicit!. Thanks for your patience.